# Setting background colour for a SurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, background, background-color, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I am building a paint application for android. Extending the FingerPaint application sample provided with the SDK. However, unlike FingerPaint, I'm using SurfaceView with a separate rendering thread to draw to the surface. All this is very standard and straightforward. Working well. I want to, however, give a White coloured background to the painting surface, so it's like drawing on a white paper. The default background is black coloured. 
The thread of my surface view, calls the onDraw() method of the view.

The problem I'm facing here is, if I set a background colour or background resource to my SurfaceView, this background overwrites the previous drawing of the surface, when the view is rendered the next time. I will explain this with an example:

Suppose I set the background to white colour. Now, the application starts, with my SurfaceView having the white colour. Ok, so far good. Now, I draw a red coloured line on this surface, with my finger. The line is now shown on the white surface. Good. Now, this is supposed to be a painting app, and suppose I want to draw a car. So, then, I draw my 2nd red line, with my finger. The 2nd line is drawn on the screen, but the 1st one, which I drew previously, vanishes. That is, because I have set some background to my SurfaceView, the background is drawn again, thus overwriting the 1st line that was drawn. Now the screen shows only the 2nd line drawn.

Obviously, I do not want this to happen. The code works perfectly, when I don't attempt to change the background (that is, both lines are shown, on a default black background, no background effectively). But when I set some desired background, this thing happens. Is there a way to somehow have a *static* background, that is not drawn every time? I want the background to be drawn only once, all the subsequent drawings should happen *on* this background. I don't want the android runtime , to draw the background, every time it draws my view, thus overwriting all drawing present on that view, from previous renderings. Any way to work around this?

The things I have tried, to achieve this are:

1. Setting the background colour of my SurfaceView using android:background in XML.
2. Doing the above, using the concept of style. (specifying a style value and referencing it in the layout file). The style just defines the background colour as #FFFFFFFF (white).
3. Setting the style of 2, to the parent view of the SurfaceView (a RelativeLayout).
4. Setting the style of 2, to the entire application, as a theme,using android:theme in my manifest file.
5. Setting the background drawable of my SurfaceView to an image which is plain and white-coloured.
6. Calling the setBackgroundColor for my SurfaceView from the code as, this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE).

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have that problem too.

Comment: Looks like this answer suggests you can paint the background color.  It worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104789/how-to-set-backgroundcolor-to-a-surfaceview-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [android's doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html):

> The surface is Z ordered so that it is behind the window holding its
>   SurfaceView; the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its
>   surface to be displayed. The view hierarchy will take care of
>   correctly compositing with the Surface any siblings of the SurfaceView
>   that would normally appear on top of it. This can be used to place
>   overlays such as buttons on top of the Surface, though note however
>   that it can have an impact on performance since a full alpha-blended
>   composite will be performed each time the Surface changes

so if you change the z order of surface view via:

```
setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

this will work, but then you cannot put any other view on top of surface view.

Answer (score 1):

Now I also tried overlaying my SurfaceView over another View with a white background, and setting the SurfaceView to be fully transparent. I used FrameLayout for this. That is, a View with a white background, overlayed upon which is my SurfaceView set to fully transparent.

This also failed to work. So now I have come to conclusion that the background colour of SurfaceView cannot be changed. So now I have dropped SurfaceView, and using a normal view, instead for my drawings. So far, there has not been any performance loss observed. But, it feels kind of wrong to drop an efficient implementation , just because SurfaceView doesn't let me change it's background colour.