# Set Background color of Surface View

Tags: android, surfaceview

I want to set a background color to the surface view to my camera surface view.

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104789/how-to-set-backgroundcolor-to-a-surfaceview-in-android) for implementing the same. But this example is not complete. Can anyone please help me with some other useful link.

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

There's a workaround to do this.

1. add a parent viewgroup for the surfaceview, set the background color to this viewgroup instead of the surfaceview;

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

       <com.example.surfacetest.MySurface
           android:id="@+id/surface"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. add the following for the SurfaceView instance;

   ```
   surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
   surfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
   ```

Now you get the background color you want and the surfaceview is tanslucent.

Comment: This should be marked as a correct answer. It works like a charm.

Comment: @wrkwrk: This works, but doing this I am not able to overlay any view top of SurfaceView. Do we have any option other than setXOrderOnTop(true)?

Comment: surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true) Do bad overlay + brokes zoom, map and etc. So be carefull

Answer (score 6):

use surfaceview_obj.setBackgroundColor (int color) to set background color..

to set white color as background use this code

```
surfaceview_obj.setBackgroundColor(0Xffffffff);
```

[check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29)

Comment: Hi @Swarnedu. Your answer is right, but it will make the Surface View as opaque, I just want to set a transparent background color

Comment: I am not sure but just give a try with this color code 0X00ffffff

Comment: I have checked it. It always makes the opaque surface view

Comment: Have u tried to draw a blank canvas on surfaceview? 

to create blank canvas check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001455/saving-canvas-to-bitmap-on-android/15012700#15012700

Answer (score 3):

just draw a Rect object with canvas.drawRect(). set the co ordinates to 0,0,screenX,screenY

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please elaborate your question (add examples and a more in-depth explaination).

Comment: Though this doesn't answer the question directly (original poster wanted a way to have his surfaceview translucent with a white background underneath).  For those who just want to make their surfaceview white, another option is to use:

canvas.drawRGB(255,255,255);

Comment: or simply `drawColor`

Answer (score 2):

you have to do a little hack-around to make any background work in SurfaceView, like this:

override the `setBackground` and `setBackgroundDrawable` methods

```
   Drawable background

   @Override
   public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
      this.background = background;
   }

   @Override
   public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
      this.background = background;
   }
```

don't forget to call `setBounds` on the drawable

```
   @Override
   protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
      super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
      matrix = null;
      if (background != null)
         background.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
   }
```

then on the code you're locking, drawing, unlocking and posting the canvas you add the background

```
   Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
   if (background != null)
      background.draw(c);

   // do your stuff here

   holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

works for both XML and Java backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
surfaceview.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put ARGB value in your draw method before your drawing(e.g. rect, circle etc). I have set it white. The last parameter is transparency.

c.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

Comment: The *last* parameter is transparency in **A**RGB?